# Disable wrapping in Psql output

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

When using Psql in Linux, if the result of my SQL query contains many columns or long strings of data, it will wrap the initial view and only once I scroll to the side will it stop wrapping and show each row on a separate line.

I've tried various [`\pset` options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html) such as `format unaligned`, `format aligned`, `format wrapped`, `columns 0`, `columns 1000`, but none seemed to *fully* stop wrapping unless I generate static output to a file.

How can I set it to never wrap the output while still being scrollable and showing the result using the default ascii table format?

Comment: Checkout [pspg](https://github.com/okbob/pspg), a pager specifically designed for PostgreSQL use.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`Psql` uses a system viewer to show its output in the console. In `bash` it likely uses `less` for the scrollable/page-able features it provides. To use a different viewer or use different settings, you just need to set the `PAGER` environment variable.

Running `psql` to use `less` with the `-S` or `--chop-long-lines` option seemed to work for me:

```
PAGER="less -S" psql
```

You can also toggle this feature while viewing output in `less` by typing `-S` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: `psql() ( PAGER="less -S" command psql "$@" )`

Comment: My PSQL version uses `less -S` by default it seems, is there anyway to turn on wrapping without turning off pager?

Answer (score 26):

To disable the wrapped output of the select query.

**\pset pager on** 
and 
**\pset pager off** to switch back to the older output view.

Comment: This turns off the pager completely, preventing scrolling up and down through large datasets (it will try to print the whole output to the terminal). Using @Silveri's tip still lets you use the pager for scrolling but just prevents wrapping.

Answer (score 19):

The default pager for `psql` is `less`. Then for no wrapped lines must be use `less -S`.
`PAGER="less -S" psql` is a good aproach. But **inside** `psql` you can use

```
\setenv PAGER 'less -S'
```

Then, to toggle it off and back on, use

```
\pset pager off
\pset pager on
```

Answer (score 15):

less's `-F` or `-S` flag will causes `\d some_table` to not show any output in some cases.

```
-F or --quit-if-one-screen
    Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be 
    displayed on the first screen.

-S or --chop-long-lines
    Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped rather than folded. 
    That is, the portion of a long line that does not fit in the screen width is 
    not shown. The default is to fold long lines; that is, display the remainder 
    on the next line.
```

Use them like this:

```
PAGER="less -S" psql
```

Seems safer at the inconvenience of having to manually exit less.

Comment: Thanks! Simply typing -S then enter will disable line wrap while looking at psql query output

Answer (score 9):

probably you should use `aligned` format for output:

```
\pset format aligned
```

You can check all available formats to fit your needs:

```
\pset format TAB
aligned          html             latex-longtable  unaligned        
asciidoc         latex            troff-ms         wrapped
```

Also you should check `PAGER` configured value in your environment

Comment: `aligned` inserts the results into an ASCII-art table for me, which for long values means that I get many lines of `-----` to create the table header before the actual values. `unaligned` avoids this.

Comment: for me it was better with `\pset format wrapped`.

Comment: you could add -t and it will skip the table headers. And -q to skip some of the other headers.