# Postgres psql output text wrapping when converting to json

Tags: json, postgresql, base64, psql, word-wrap

I have a strange behavior in psql that makes long base64 encoded text break with newline when converting to json string

I encode my text in base64 as followed:

```
db=> select encode('-------------------------------------------------------------------'::bytea, 'base64');
                                    encode                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0t+
 LS0tLS0tLS0tLQ==
```

Here the output text is wrapped, that's not actually a problem.
But then if I convert this base64 encoded text to a json string using `to_json()`:

```
db=> select to_json(encode('-------------------------------------------------------------------'::bytea, 'base64')::text);
                                             to_json                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0t\nLS0tLS0tLS0tLQ=="
```

Here the base64 encoded text in json has a new line character (`\n`) near the end <strike>which totally breaks the base64 code when decoding</strike> (Thanks [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) for the correction!). **The new line character gives me trouble later in my program and I'm searching a solution to fix it in psql.**

I've tried using the `/pset format` command or setting `PAGER="less -SF" psql ...` (from other stackoverflow issue: [Disable wrapping in Psql output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850860/disable-wrapping-in-psql-output)) but without success.

The only solution I've found (**and a very dirty one**) is to do:

```
db=> select to_json(regexp_replace((select to_json(encode('----------------------------------------------------------'::bytea, 'base64')::text))::text, '(\\n|")', '', 'g'));
                                      to_json                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLQ=="
```

Here I convert to JSON string (with `to_json()`) then I remove the JSON string quotes and new line characters (with `regexp_replace()`) and then re-converting to JSON again to get the expected result.

Comment: I don't understand how that breaks base64. base64 encoded values *do* contain line breaks.

Comment: That I didn't know. Apparently the base64 decoding do indeed work on that encoded value but my problem is actually elsewhere in my program where I just can't have new line characters in my base64 field. Is this new line character really inevitable here?

Comment: Unfortunately the line length of 76 bytes is hard coded in the PostgreSQL source. There is no comment that explains that choice.